# Trouble running sumo flow demo example

Tags: sumo, flow-project

Repost from user Jin G.

---

After going through the Flow installation tutorial I tried to run the sumo demo example using the following terminal command:

`python examples/sumo/sugiyama.py`

I got the following error message: `Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost: 40335 [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Any thoughts on what to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of retrying and searching I found a fix..

My issue was that I did not activate the conda environment when running the simulations.

To do so before running any simulations type the following into the command prompt:
`source activate flow`